# htaccess deny from http

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know how to use the apache rewrite engine to redirect http requests to https

However, for the task at hand (an app exchanging data with the server via https) what we actually want is for http requests to simply be denied.  I have tried the following but it does not work

```
​Deny from %{HTTPS}=off
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply take parts of directives and scrumble them together somehow. You need to obey the syntax of those directives, otherwise the engine cannot make sense of them. And will throw an internal syntax error.

Two things you need to do:

1. You need to start monitoring your http server's error log file. That is where you can see those errors. *You cannot implement web logic without monitoring that file in your development environment* . And you definitely should look into it in your production environment too from time to time.
2. You should start to read the documentation of the tools you are using. The apache http server project is a good example for the high quality of open your products: it offers an excellent documentation that is precise and comes with lots of great examples. Start with the documentation of the rewriting module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

This would be a suggestion to implement the logic you have in mind:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Other variants are possible, for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```